# llamada SOAP WSDL usando servicio Java lanza error 500 Http 200

Tags: java, java-ee, spring-boot, soap, wsdl

Estoy llamando a un método de un servicio SOAP WSDL (con o sin parámetros) usando Java con Spring. Llamo a mi servicio Spring con PostMan y este se encarga de llamar al SOAP WSDL.

_el_proyecto_

Usé el plugin “jaxws-maven-plugin” en la versión 2.5, lo configuré en el POM.xml y con el comando “mvn jaxws:wsimport” logré autogenerar el package y las clases de cada método SOAP WSDL. Me autogeneró bastantes clases, de lo autogenerado pude analizar que:

Por cada método generó estos archivos:

- NomMetodoEjemplo.java
- NomMetodoEjemploCriteriaVO.java
- NomMetodoEjemploOutVO.java
- NomMetodoEjemploResponse.java

Y otras que tienen relación con el propio servicio:

- NomServicioEjemplo.java
- NomServicioEjemploPortType.java (interface)

*codigo y error*

Construí el código basándome en los ejemplos de este enlace: 
[how-to-do-a-call-through-a-javax-xml-ws-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922655/how-to-do-a-call-through-a-javax-xml-ws-service)

```
String wsdlURL = "http://10.20.30.40:6789/ws/juegosService?wsdl";
String namespace = "http://services.juegos.com/";
String serviceName = "JuegosService";
QName serviceQN = new QName(namespace, serviceName);

JuegosService js = new JuegosService(new URL(wsdlURL),serviceQN);

JuegosServicePortType port = js.getJuegosServicePort();
ConsultaDetalladaJuegoCriteriaVO criteriaIn = new ConsultaDetalladaJuegoCriteriaVO();
ConsultaDetalladaJuegoOutVO criteriaOut = new ConsultaDetalladaJuegoOutVO();
criteriaIn.setCodigoJuego("0011223344");
criteriaIn.setTipoJuego("5");
criteriaOut = port.consultaDetalladaJuego(criteriaIn); //ERROR AQUÍ
```

Error

```
{
    "result": false,
    "status": {
        "code": "500",
        "message": "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
    },
    "error": {
        "message": "El servidor ha enviado el código de estado HTTP 200: OK",
        "field": ""
    }
}
```

**Nota**: Evité instanciar Service.java como en el enlace de ejemplo y usé JuegosService.java (autogenerado por jaxws) para así evitar un error por no apuntar correctamente al puerto del servicio.

Alguna sugerencia de porque me podría estar enviando un error 500 con un HTTP 200??

Mi primera pregunta!!

y gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cordial saludo:

Un código de respuesta 500 por parte del servidor implica que hubo una situación no controlada (como excepción o error) y por lo tanto no hay una respuesta satisfactoria(https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP).

En este caso se debe contactar al proveedor del servicio para que se estudie el error.